# Why does join . (flip fmap) have type ((A -> B) -> A) -> (A -> B) -> B?

Tags: haskell, types, monads, functor

Some playing around with functors and monads in ghci led me to a value whose type and behaviour I would like to understand better.

The type of `\x -> join . x` is `(Monad m) => (a -> m (m b)) -> (a -> m b)` and the type of `\y -> y . (flip fmap)` is `(Functor f) => ((a -> b) -> f b) -> (f a -> c)`.

Version 8.2.2 of ghci permits the definition `h = join . (flip fmap)`.

> Why does `h` have type `((A -> B) -> A) -> (A -> B) -> B`?

In particular, why do the functor and monad constraints disappear? Is this really the correct and expected behaviour? As a follow up, I would also like to ask:

> Why does evaluating `h (\f -> f u) (\x -> x + v)` for integers `u` and `v` give `u + 2v` in every case?

Comment: Because `(->) a` is a `Monad` and `Functor`.

Comment: Actually every `Monad` is also a `Functor`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**In short**: due to type deduction, Haskell knows that `m` and `f` are in fact a partially instantiated arrow.

## Deriving the type

Well let us do the math. The function `join . (flip fmap)` is basically your given lambda expression `\x -> join . x` with as argument `(flip fmap)`, so:

```
h = (\x -> join . x) (flip fmap)
```

Now the lambda expression has type:

```
(\x -> join . x) :: Monad m =>   (a -> m (m b)) -> (a -> m b)
```

Now the argument `flip fmap` has type:

```
flip fmap        :: Functor f => f c -> ((c -> d) -> f d)
```

(we here use `c` and `d` instead of `a` and `b` to avoid confusion between two *possibly* different types).

So that means that the type of `flip fmap` is the same as the type of the *argument* of the lambda expression, hence we know that:

```
  Monad m =>   a   -> m (m b)
~ Functor f => f c -> ((c -> d) -> f d)
---------------------------------------
a ~ f c, m (m b) ~ ((c -> d) -> f d)
```

So we now know that `a` has the same type as `f c` (this is the meaning of the tilde `~`).

But we have to do some extra computations:

```
  Monad m =>   m (m b)
~ Functor f => ((c -> d) -> f d)
--------------------------------
m ~ (->) (c -> d), m b ~ f d
```

Hence we know that `m` is the same as `(->) (c -> d)` (basically this is a function where we know that input type, here `(c -> d)`, and the output type is a type parameter of `m`.

So that means that `m b ~ (c -> d) -> b ~ f d`, so this means that `f ~ (->) (c -> d)` and `b ~ d`. An extra consequence is that since `a ~ f c`, we know that `a ~ (c -> d) -> c`

So to list what we derived:

```
f ~ m
m ~ (->) (c -> d)
b ~ d
a ~ (c -> d) -> c
```

So we now can "specialize" the types of both our lambda expression, and our `flip fmap` function:

```
(\x -> join . x)
    :: (((c -> d) -> c) -> (c -> d) -> (c -> d) -> d) -> ((c -> d) -> c) -> (c -> d) -> d
flip fmap
    ::  ((c -> d) -> c) -> (c -> d) -> (c -> d) -> d
```

and type of `flip fmap` now perfectly matches with the type of the argument of the lambda expression. So the type of `(\x -> join . x) (flip fmap)` is the result type of the lambda expression type, and that is:

```
(\x -> join . x) (flip fmap)
    :: ((c -> d) -> c) -> (c -> d) -> d
```

But now we of course did not yet obtained the implementation of this function. We are however already a step further.

## Deriving the implementation

Since we now know that `m ~ (->) (c -> d)`, we know we should lookup the [arrow instance of a monad](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-804):

> ```
> instance Monad ((->) r) where
>     f >>= k = \ r -> k (f r) r
> ```

So for a given function `f :: r -> a`, as left operand, and a function `k :: a -> (r -> b) ~ a -> r -> b` as operand, we construct a new function that maps a variable `x` to `k` applied to `f` applied to `x`, and `x`. It is thus a way to perform some sort of preprocessing on an input variable `x`, and then do the processing both taking into account the preprocessing and the original view (well this is *an* interpretation a human reader can use).

Now [**`join :: Monad m => m (m a) -> m a`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:join) is [implemented as](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#join):

> ```
> join :: Monad m => m (m a) -> m a
> join x = x >>= id
> ```

So for the `(->) r` monad, this means that we implement this as:

```
-- specialized for `m ~ (->) a
join f = \r -> id (f r) r
```

Since [**`id :: a -> a`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:id) (the identity function) returns its argument, we can further simplify it to:

```
-- specialized for `m ~ (->) a
join f = \r -> (f r) r
```

or cleaner:

```
-- specialized for `m ~ (->) a
join f x = f x x
```

So it basically is given a function `f`, and will then apply an argument twice to that function.

Furthermore we know that the `Functor` instance for the arrow type is [defined as](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-794):

> ```
> instance Functor ((->) r) where
>     fmap = (.)
> ```

So it is basically used as a "post processor" on the result of the function: we construct a new function that will do the post processing with the given function.

So now that we specialized the function enough for the given `Functor`/`Monad`, we can derive the implementation as:

```
-- alternative implementation
h = (.) (\f x -> f x x) (flip (.))
```

or by using more lambda expressions:

```
h = \a -> (\f x -> f x x) ((flip (.)) a)
```

which we can now further specialize as:

```
h = \a -> (\f x -> f x x) ((\y z -> z . y) a)

-- apply a in the lambda expression
h = \a -> (\f x -> f x x) (\z -> z . a)

-- apply (\z -> z . a) in the first lambda expression
h = \a -> (\x -> (\z -> z . a) x x)

-- cleaning syntax
h a = (\x -> (\z -> z . a) x x)

-- cleaning syntax
h a x = (\z -> z . a) x x

-- apply lambda expression
h a x = (x . a) x

-- remove the (.) part
h a x = x (a x)
```

So `h` basically takes two arguments: `a` and `x`, it then performs function application with `a` as function and `x` as parameter, and the output is passed to the `x` function again.

## Sample usage

As sample usage you use:

```
h (\f -> f u) (\x -> x + v)
```

or nicer:

```
h (\f -> f u) (+v)
```

so we can analyze this like:

```
   h (\f -> f u) (+v)
-> (+v) ((\f -> f u) (+v))
-> (+v) ((+v) u)
-> (+v) (u+v)
-> ((u+v)+v)
```

So we add `u+v` to `v`.

Comment: `const u` and `\f -> f u` aren't equivalent. I believe you meant `($ u)`

Comment: @M.Aroosi: correct, somehow that was not edited out of the answer. Updated, many thanks :).

Answer (score 1):

Types *line up* easier with `>>>`:

```
                          a   ->     b                       >>>
                                     b              -> c     ::
                          a   ->                       c
```

Here, we have

```
join . flip fmap  ==  flip fmap >>> join

flip fmap :: Functor f => f a -> ((a -> b) -> f b )
join      :: Monad   m =>        (m          (m b)) -> m b
----------------------------------------------------------
flip fmap >>> join ::
 (Functor f, Monad m) =>  f a  ->                      m b   , ((a -> b) ->) ~ m, f ~ m
                   ::
 (Functor f, Monad f) =>  f a  ->                      f b   , f ~ ((a -> b) ->)
                   ::    ((a -> b) -> a) -> ((a -> b) -> b)
```

Simple, mechanical, mundane.

---

To *see* what it *does*, combinatory style definitions are usually easiest to twiddle with,

```
(join . flip fmap) f g x =
 join (flip fmap f) g x =          -- join f x = f x x
 (`fmap` f) g g x =                -- f `fmap` g = f . g
 (g . f) g x 
 g (f g) x
```

So we don't need `x` after all (or do we?). The `join` and `fmap` definitions for functions are given in the margins. We've arrived at

```
(join . flip fmap) f g = g (f g)   -- f :: (a -> b) -> a,  g :: a -> b 
                                   -- f g :: a  , g (f g) :: b
```

Another way is starting from the types, going by the rule of modus ponens,

```
            ((a -> b) -> a)    (a -> b)        --       f  g
            ---------------------------
(a -> b)                 a                     --  g   (f  g)
---------------------------------------
      b
```

Comment: Thank you! Your answer make it very clear how the type of m can be inferred purely syntactically.